# Get second, third, etc. stored procedure recordset schema without executing

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Given a stored procedure in SQL Server 2019+, is there a way to get the number and the schema of the recordsets, **past the first one**, that it will return if executed, **without actually executing**? Maybe some kind of compiled SQL analysis combined with execution plan interrogation could help.

Assume there are no conditional/dynamic SELECTs in it.

"Impossible" is an acceptable answer.

---

The methods for retrieving the *first* recordset's schema are adequately covered by other questions. I'm explicitly after multirecordset procedures.

Comment: Not sure about all of them, you can definitely get the first resultset, with, you guessed it `sp_describe_first_result_set`

Comment: Good one. I don't see anything about the subsequent recordsets though :(

Comment: Or, alternatively, [`sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-describe-first-result-set-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16). Personally I prefer this, as it's a function, so you can choose what columns you want, and use it in conjunction with other objects.

Comment: All of the linked questions' answers boil down to the first recordset. I'll edit and reopen.

Comment: A [`TSqlParser Class`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.transactsql.scriptdom.tsqlparser?view=sql-transactsql-161) would let you pick apart the syntax of a SP, but the semantics require a lot more work. Somewhere in the back of my brain is a horrible notion of parsing the SP, changing the first `select` the returns a recordset to add `into BitBucket000` (with incrementing number), and getting the schema of the new first recordset. Lather, rinse, repeat.

Comment: Let's put it this way, you won't be able to do anything with 2,3,4th resultset from SQL other than sending it to the wire, so why are you looking for this info? You can figure out the resultsets by your client application by using the good old SET FMTONLY ON; clause and executing procedure

Comment: Set results to Text, then run SET NOCOUNT ON;SET FMTONLY ON; EXEC [your stored proc];

Comment: @siggemannen: I'm trying to generate a strongly typed wrapper, naturally.

Comment: @Vitaly: that sounds like "impossible without executing". Which is an acceptable answer, just not the one I was hoping for :)

Comment: @SevaAlekseyev, i'm pretty sure someone already did that , dapper etc :) Don't do it in sql anyway, unless you're writing strongly type wrappers in tsql as well. Btw, SET FMTONLY doesn't execute the procedure, it uses same methodic as dm_exec_describe_result_set and just processes the code inside

Comment: Who said anything about doing it in TSQL? :) Now, `SET FMTONLY` - I understand it makes the SELECTs in the SP not return the records (only the metadata), but what about side effects?

Comment: Post's tag is t-sql :)

Comment: I assumed the "retrieve the metadata" piece would be somehow in TSQL. The rest of the wrapper generation isn't, and the wrapper itself isn't either, but that's irrelevant to the to at hand.

Comment: SET FMTONLY doesn't generate any side effects, only returns eventual metadata, because it doesn't execute sql. you can even try by doing: `set FMTONLY ON if 1 = 0 select 'test'` it will still output something